# How to Sort UTF-8 String which Contains Digits & Characters?

Tags: c, string, qt, sorting, sqlite

I am working on Program(in c) which require sorting.
One of the requirement of sorting is : Digits Sorting.

Digit sorting shall be completed from least significant digit (i.e. the rightmost digit) and to the most significant
digit (i.e. the leftmost digit) such that the numbers 21, 2, and 11 are sorted as follows: 2, 11, 21.

The given string is in UTF-8 and may contains Special Characters,Digits,Latin letters ,Cyrillic letters ,Hiragana/Katakana etc.

It give following sorting Order :

1

1a

1b

2

11

110

110a

Henry7

Henry24

Comment: Before implementing some requirement, we must understand it. What does 'Digits Sorting' means when there are also letters? Are we suppose to discard non-numeric characters or what? YOu give an example input - are you clear about the example output? If so, give it to us.

Comment: leonbloy @ : Yes , you are right. Before implementing some requirement, we must understand it.   No ,we are not suppose to discard non-numeric characters. The above given strings are output of sorting ....Like following sorting Oder is need : 1. 7ash  2. 22ash 3. ash4   4. ash22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) (International Components for Unicode), which includes a [collation (sorting) API](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation).

Comment: Then you will have to write a collator youself, in unicode.org there are machine readable files to tell you in which order to sort characters.http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: Actually QString uses libICU under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "sort numerical characters in text strings as numbers." You may try using Qt's [QString::localeAwareCompare()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare-1) which makes use of locale and platform settings to compare strings. At least on OS X, this should mean it will respect the user selected locale which include the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can convert it to utf16 and sort by code point value if you don't care about locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)'s custom comparator function by checking with [QString::localeAwareCompare()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare-1).

**Comparator function:**

```cpp
void sortLocaleAware(QStringList &sList)
{
    std::sort(sList.begin(), sList.end(), [](const QString &s1, const QString &s2){
        return s1.localeAwareCompare(s2) < 0;
    });
}
```

**Usage:**

```cpp
QStringList myList = { "4a", "3b", "52a" ,"13ş", "34İ" };
sortLocaleAware(myList);
```